# Using Big Query UDF during select

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, udf

I have a table, that contains uuid and some other values for users.

Also, I have the following UDF function in BQ that calculates user_group by given uuid, based on MD5 and crc32 values:

```
function GetGroup(uuid) {...
}

function getUserGroup(r, emit) {
emit ({group: GetGroup(String(r.uuid)), uuid: r.uuid
  });
}

bigquery.defineFunction(
'get_group',
['uuid'],    
[{'name': 'group', 'type': 'string'}, {'name': 'uuid', 'type': 'string'}],
getUserGroup);
```

So, to extract the user value I need to do something like:

```
SELECT
  group,
  uuid
FROM
  get_group(
    SELECT
      uuid
    FROM
      [MY_TABLE] )
```

This is not very useful, because I would like to extract the same user_group for uuid's in couple of different tables and I don't want to define function "get_group" every time I want to use it. Additionally, if I want all fields from the table I need to JOIN the result with original table or hardcode the table schema in UDF.

Is there any convenient way to use UDF similar to any built-in function in Big Query? For example:

```
SELECT
  uuid,  
  get_group(uuid)
FROM
  [ANY_TABLE_WITH_UUID_FIELD]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the best option for you is to use [Scalar User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions) introduced with BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)).

This gives you great extent of composability that you are looking for
Pay attention to [Including external libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions#including-external-libraries) feature. It allows you to reference your heavy code as an external code libraries, while keeping your inline code minimal / readable / etc.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_group(uuid STRING) 
  RETURNS STRING 
  LANGUAGE js AS 
"""
  return get_group(uuid);
"""

OPTIONS (
  library="gs://your-bucket/path/to/your-lib.js"
);

SELECT
  uuid,  
  get_group(uuid)
FROM
  [ANY_TABLE_WITH_UUID_FIELD]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to express this sort of filter using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/); see also the [user-defined function reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions). Here is an example:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_group(uuid STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS """
function get_group(uuid) {
  // (Your code here)
  return uuid + 'foo';
}

return get_group(uuid);
""";

WITH MyTable AS (
  SELECT uuid FROM UNNEST(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']) AS uuid
)
SELECT uuid, get_group(uuid) AS `group`
FROM MyTable;
```

To run this query in the BigQuery UI, uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options".